# Testflight send Feedback

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, testflight

I got a problem with TestFlight and their "feedback" function.
I'm starting a session(`takeoff`) and then I excecute the command "`TestFlight.OpenFeedbackView`"
Then i've got the View and the possibility to send, but if i want to send nothing happens.
The view hides itself and there is no feedback on Testflight.com.

Can anybody help me?

thank you very much;)

Comment: Two things: first, are these appearing now after waiting a few minutes?  second, you must actually publish the build through TestFlight and install the version you are testing through TestFlight for some of these features.

Comment: I've done your two things.But still nothing happens. Maybe it won't work because I use monotouch? Maybe an Binding error?

Comment: Do you see session info for your app on TestFlight?  You should see a log entry for session started and ended.

Comment: Yes i can see the session info and there is a session started and ended as well as the checkpoints. But no feedback=(

Comment: Did you solve this? I seem to have the same problem, even though I do it native.